# store data in every minute what should use Service, AsyncTask

Tags: database, service, android-asynctask

I want to store data in database in every minute . For the same what should I use Service, AsyncTask or anything else. I go through various link which made me more confused .

I read the developer guide and came to know about getWritableDatabase

> Database upgrade may take a long time, you should not call this method from the application main thread,

Then first I think I will use AsyncTask then about this

> AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.)

After that I think I can use Service then about Service

> A Service is not a thread. It is not a means itself to do work off of the main thread (to avoid Application Not Responding errors).

Here I am not able to understand what  should I use to store data in database periodically. Please help me here as struck badly.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant do a lot work on the UI thread, so making database operations you could choose different approaches, few of them that I prefer to use are listed below;

1. Create a thread pool and execute each database operation via a thread, this reduces load on UI thread, also it never initializes lot of threads.
2. You can use services for updating the database operations. since services running on UI thread you cant write your operations in Services, so that you have to create a separate thread inside service method. or you can use Intent service directly since it is not working on UI Thread.

[here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/run-code.html) is developer documentation on thread pool in android

and [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) is the documentation for IntentService

**UPDATE**

This will send an intent to your service every minute without using any processor time in your activity in between

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MyServiceReceiver.class);
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,  0, myIntent, 0);

  AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
  calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 60); // first time
  long frequency= 60 * 1000; // in ms 
  alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), frequency, pendingIntent);
```

Before that check if you really need a service to be started in each minute. or if you can have one service which checks for the data changes in each minute, starting new service would consume maybe more resources than checking itself.

**UPDATE 2**

```
private ping() {
  // periodic action here.
  scheduleNext();
}

private scheduleNext() {
  mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() { ping(); }
  }, 60000);
}

int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int x, int y) {
  mHandler = new android.os.Handler();
  ping();
  return STICKY;
}
```

this is a simple example like that you can do

Comment: Thanks .... its a great help to me ... I ll check both .....I have one more question    If I use Service then how can I pass data from activity in every minute as I am getting data in activity and then store in DB.

Comment: would you mind elaborating the use case little more ?

Comment: Actually I am storing location data in db which I am continuously getting .So I think to store data in database every minute. For the same as u suggested I can use Intent Service. But I dont want to start new Service every minute. I just want same Service always run and take data from activity and store in db. So I was wondering how can I pass data to same Service in every minute from my activity.

Comment: How can I have one service which will always run and takes input from activity. Please help as struck badly

Comment: Thanks for the response but here I am not able to understand how passing the data to same service from activity. Request you to explain the sample more.